# Moving page from Updatepanel to AccordianPane 'hides' previously visible property

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to move a page from an AJAX UpdatePanel to an Ajax Control Toolkit AccordianPane. When I run the app I get the following error :

> DataBinding: 'AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionContentPanel' does not
>   contain a property with the name 'IsNdmaVisible'.

[image: DataBinding: 'AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionContentPanel' does not contain a property with the name 'IsNdmaVisible']

Here is a code snippet from the page I'm embedding in the AccordianPaneControl, with the property *IsNdmaVisible* in question, as referred to in the DataBinder.Eval method:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ScenarioEditor.ascx.cs"
Inherits="Clients.Views.Controls.ScenarioEditor" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/SharedUserControls/AjaxMonthCalendar.ascx" TagName="AjaxMonthCalendar" TagPrefix="ajaxMonthCalendar" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/SharedUserControls/AjaxFcdMonthCalendar.ascx" TagName="AjaxFcdMonthCalendar" TagPrefix="ajaxMonthCalendar" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="m_ScenarioEditorUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="m_ScenarioEditorPanel" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="m_ScenarioEditorPanelResource1">
        <table class="layout-table input-strech">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                        <table class="layout-table" >
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="m_SnowBallCheckBox" ValidationGroup="ScenarioStrategies" runat="server"
                                        Width="100px" meta:resourcekey="m_SnowBallCheckBox" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="m_NDMACheckBox" ValidationGroup="ScenarioStrategies" runat="server"
                                        Width="100px" **Visible='<%# (bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container, "IsNdmaVisible") %>'**
                                        Enabled='<%# (bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container, "IsNdmaEnabled") %>' meta:resourcekey="m_NDMACheckBox" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
    </asp:Panel>
    <div id="flag">
    </div>
    <asp:Literal ID="StartUpScript" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        ScenarioEditor.StartUp();
    </script>
    </asp:Literal>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Inasmuch embedding the above ScenarioEditor.ascx page, here with the original code snippet which works perfectly, followed by my new code, which obviously breaks (I'm including the assembly and code references  only once for both snippets):

Reference and 'exteral' code registering:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Shared/CareMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EditScenario.aspx.cs" Inherits="Clients.Views.EditScenario" meta:resourcekey="PageResource1"  %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Clients/Controls/ScenarioEditor.ascx" TagName="ScenarioEditor" TagPrefix="clientControls" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/SharedUserControls/CollapsibleContentPanel.ascx" TagName="CollapsibleContentPanel" TagPrefix="sharedControls" %>
<%@ Register src="~/SharedUserControls/AjaxCalendar.ascx" tagname="AjaxCalendar" tagprefix="ajaxCalendar" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

Working Code:

```
<asp:Content ID="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <sharedControls:CollapsibleContentPanel ID="m_ScenarioEditorPanel" runat="server"  style="margin-bottom: 1em">
        <Title>
            Scenario Details
        </Title>
        <Content>
            <div >
                <asp:HiddenField ID="labelForRadio"  Value="" runat="server"/>
            </div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ButtonsPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div style="float:left;">
                        <clientControls:ScenarioEditor runat="server" ID="m_ScenarioEditor" />                                
                    </div> 
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </Content>
    </sharedControls:CollapsibleContentPanel>
</asp:Content>
```

My code:

```
<ajaxToolkit:Accordion ID="Accordian1" runat="server">
        <Panes>
            <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID="ScenarioDetails" runat="server">
                <Header>Scenario Details</Header>
                <Content>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ButtonsPanel" runat="server" BackColor="Yellow">
                      <ContentTemplate>   
                        <div style="float:left;">
                            <clientControls:ScenarioEditor runat="server" ID="m_ScenarioEditor" />                                
                        </div>  
                          </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </Content>
            </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>     
        </Panes>
</ajaxToolkit:Accordion>
```